# jQuery.fileuploadui, doesn't show thumbnail preview in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have been referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971662/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-doesnt-show-thumbnail-preview-image/18284685#18284685) about showing the preview image using jquery file upload. I have the same code using URL.createObjectURL, but its not working in IE9. I need to support ie9 for file upload. Is there a fix or workaround for IE9 that can show the image preview using this plugin?

Thanks in advance, appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, image thumbnail not is supported in ie9.