# BlueImp jQuery File Upload preview improvement to thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, thumbnails, blueimp

I just integrate the basic UI example into one app. What I want to achieve is to add a specific thumbnails for some of the files that cannot be render in the preview. For instance, I will like to add some images for word, excels, ppt, and pdfs. I want to get a fixed image.

I know how to generate previews of this files, but first I want to try something simple.

I was checking this question [Blueimp Jquery File Upload : Doesn't show thumbnail preview image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971662/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-doesnt-show-thumbnail-preview-image)

In my case the control previews videos and images properly.

[image]

They talk about modify this function in jquery.fileupload-ui.js

```
 _renderPreviews: function (data) {
            data.context.find('.preview').each(function (index, elm) {
                $(elm).append(data.files[index].preview);
            });
        },
```

That's the only part that I have to modify to make this work?

If anyone could explain to me, how is the internal flow of the control to generate the preview of the images. I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I could not modify the preview functionality in the control. 
[image]

However, I achieve some customization in the second render of the items uploaded after finished.
[image]
It looks better that before.  For achieving this, I modified

```
public ActionResult GetThumbnailFile(string folderServerPath,string name, bool thumbnail = false)
        {
            var file = GetFile(name, folderServerPath);
            var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file.Name);
            return thumbnail ? Thumb(file, contentType) : File(file.FullName, contentType);
        }

        private ActionResult Thumb(FileInfo file, string contentType)
        {
            if (contentType.StartsWith("image"))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName))
                    {
                        var thumbHeight = (int)(img.Height * (ThumbSize / (double)img.Width));
                        using (var thumb = img.GetThumbnailImage(ThumbSize, thumbHeight, () => false, IntPtr.Zero))
                        {
                            var ms = new MemoryStream();
                            thumb.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);
                            ms.Position = 0;
                            return File(ms, contentType);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // todo log exception
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (file.Extension.ToUpperInvariant())
                {
                    case ".LOG":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/txt-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    case ".PDF":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/pdf-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    case "JPEG":
                        //icon = "JPEG-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "JPG":
                        //icon = "JPEG-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "WBMP":
                        //icon = "Illustrator-File-icon128.png";
                        break;
                    case "BMP":
                        //icon = "BMP-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "TIF":
                        //icon = "Web-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "JP2":
                        //icon = "Vector-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "JBIG2":
                        //icon = "Vector-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "EMF":
                        //icon = "Photoshop-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "GIF":
                        //icon = "GIF-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "PNG":
                        //icon = "PNG-File-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case "TXT":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/txt-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    case ".DOC":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/doc-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "doc-icon-128.png";
                    case ".DOCX":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/docx-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "docx-icon-128.png";
                    case ".PST":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/pst-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "pst-icon-128.png";
                    case ".PPT":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/ppt-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "ppt-icon-128.png";
                    case ".PPTX":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/pptx-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "pptx-icon-128.png";
                    case ".HTML":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/html-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "html-icon-128.png";
                    case ".RTF":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/rtf-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "rtf-icon-128.png";
                    case ".DLL":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/dll-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "dll-icon-128.png";
                    case "EML":
                        //icon = "eml-icon-128.png";
                        break;
                    case ".FLA":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/fla-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    case ".SWF":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/fla-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "fla-icon-128.png";
                    case ".MP3":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/mp3-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    case ".XLS":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/xls-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "xls-icon-128.png";
                    case ".XLSX":
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/xlsx-icon-128.png", contentType);
                    //icon = "xlsx-icon-128.png";
                    default://unknow
                        return File("~/Images/general_documents_preview/bin-icon-128.png", contentType);

                }

            }

            return Redirect($"https://placehold.it/{ThumbSize}?text={Url.Encode(file.Extension)}");
        }
```

You can check the changes downloading the original example project from 
https://github.com/ronnieoverby/blue-imp-upload-aspnet-mvc/tree/master/src/jquploadz

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround for adding custom thumbnails after files have been uploaded, assuming you're using the blueimp javascript templates (x-tmpl) like in the demo example:  https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates

```
<span class="preview">
            {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
            {% } else {

            // Display relevant icon
            var ext = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            var icon = "icons/generic.png";

            if (ext === "pdf") {var icon="icons/pdf.png"};
            if (ext === "xls" || ext === "xlsx" || ext === "csv" || ext === "ods" || ext === "xlr") {var icon="icons/excel.png"};
            if (ext === "psd" || ext === "psb" || ext === "eps" || ext === "tif" || ext === "tiff" || ext === "indd"  || ext === "ind" || ext === "bmp" || ext === "ai") {var icon="icons/graphic.png"};
            if (ext === "tar" || ext === "rar" || ext === "tgz"  || ext === "gz" || ext === "7z" || ext === "sit" || ext === "sitx" || ext === "cab") {var icon="icons/archive.png"};
            if (ext === "docx" || ext ==="doc") {var icon="icons/word.png"};
            if (ext === "rtf" || ext === "txt" || ext === "log" || ext === "xml" || ext === "css" || ext === "htm" || ext === "html") {var icon="icons/txt.png"};
            if (ext === "zip") {var icon="icons/zip.png"};
            if (ext === "mov" || ext === "avi" || ext === "m4v" || ext === "3gp" || ext === "mpeg" || ext === "mkv"  || ext === "vob" || ext === "aaf" || ext === "asf" || ext === "wmv" || ext === "flv" || ext === "swf" || ext === "mpg" || ext === "mp4") {var icon="icons/mov.png"};
            if (ext === "ppt" || ext === "pptx" || ext === "pps") {var icon="icons/ppt.png"};
            if (ext === "pkg" || ext === "rpm") {var icon="icons/pkg.png"};
            if (ext === "dmg" || ext === "iso" || ext === "bin" || ext === "toast") {var icon="icons/dmg.png"};
            if (ext === "key" || ext === "odp") {var icon="icons/keynote.png"};
            if (ext === "pages" || ext === "odt") {var icon="icons/pages.png"};
            if (ext === "numbers") {var icon="icons/numbers.png"};
            if (ext === "wav" || ext === "aif" || ext === "aiff" || ext === "m4a" || ext === "ogg" || ext === "mp3" || ext === "caf" || ext === "aac") {var icon="icons/wav.png"};
            if (ext === "fnt" || ext === "fon" || ext === "otf" || ext === "ttf") {var icon="icons/font.png"};

            %}<img src="{%=icon%}">{% } %}


        </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the current version of jQuery File Uploader I got a default pdf preview icon  prior to upload by putting an 80x80 gif (pdf80x80.gif) in the img folder and adding this to the top of jquery.fileupload-ui.css

```
span.preview{
  background: url('../img/pdf80x80.gif') !important;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

For the post upload preview, in index.html I changed in the section labelled
"The template to display files available for download" I changed

```
<span class="preview">
    {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
    {% } %}
</span>
```

to

```
<span class="preview">
    {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
    {% } else { %}
        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="./img/pdf80x80.gif"></a>
    {% } %}
</span>
```

Caveat: My site will only allow jpg or pdf uploads, so I only need one non-image default icon.

Problems:

1. PDF icon may briefly appear during upload (use non-transparent uploading gif?)
2. PDF icon is displayed if upload fails